# Is it possible to pass action name as parameter to @Url.Action?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5

The code looks as following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Hello() {
        var name = DevExpressUtility.getSelectedItem();
        var url = '@Url.Action(' + name + ', "Home")';
        //alert(name);
        //window.open("../../Views/Home/DisplaySchema9.cshtml", "_blank", "titlebar=no,location=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,fullscreen=yes");
        window.open(url, "_blank", "titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,fullscreen=yes");
    }
</script>
```

There is error message - Unrecognized escape sequence.

Comment: No.... you are trying to evaluate a client side variable in a server side function.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. And what about using window.open? How can I set the path to selected view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really.

Looks like you have `name` that is computed client-side but then you believe the server will pick up the current value and somehow re-evaluate the url every time something changes at the client?

It won't work that way.

One of workarounds would be to not to rely on the `@Url.Action` but consider your current routing and hard-code the actual path. Assuming you have default routes, it should be as simple as

```
var url = '/Home/' + name;
```

Comment: It can't find the resource that is .cshtml file. The path is as following: site_name/Views/Home/<name>.cshtml.

Comment: That would be completely wrong, `cshtml` files are **not** routable with HTTP. The `Url.Action` always returns uris of a form `/controller/action`.

Comment: I simply want to open view file in new window. How to do it?

Comment: Just like you did but create the `url` **without** using `Url.Action`.

Comment: I'm trying it, but all path combinations I've tried so far don't work.

Comment: For example: "../../Views/Home/" + name + ".cshtml"

Comment: I am starting to believe you get it totally, completely wrong and you don't even have controllers to handle different values returned from `getSelectedItem`. In other words, you don't even know what is your **expected** path (i.e. what controller and what action you should have there).

Comment: Ok, my bad, it should be `/Home/ + name` as names are your actions. Edited my answer.

Comment: I did it in the meantime in that way, but it doesn't work as expected. Actually, I want to display particular view in full screen mode, but the content of the view is messed up and I can't get rid of title and address bar. I think it's better to try to use the full screen API.